# How can i use freopen() to redirect stdout & stdin in thread vise log-file in multi-thread application?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, logfiles, freopen

Extened question from [In multi thread application how can i redirect stderr & stdout in separate file as per thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360391/in-multi-thread-application-how-can-i-redirect-stderr-stdout-in-separate-file)

see some how i want to keep all printf and error/warning message produced in each thread in different log-file.

```
FILE * freopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode, FILE * stream );
```

freopen function  redirects 3rd argument stream into 1st argument file name. So now i want to ask you in multi-theread application can i do that with help of freopen()...  how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all resources are shared in a threaded application, including files, changing `stdin` or `stdout` in one thread changes them for all threads. If you want to change it in just a single thread then use `fork` to create a new process instead.