# how to log threadwise stack of multithreaded process in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, stack-trace

I want to record stack information of each thread of processes to a txt file in linux.

I want to use 'C/C++' programming language.

If anyone can give me possible commands or any help please reply this question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a thread wise log file and have all `stdout` and `stderr` output redirect in that log file ... 
   maybe this will help you for that: [In multi thread application how can i redirect stderr & stdout in separate file as per thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360391/in-multi-thread-application-how-can-i-redirect-stderr-stdout-in-separate-file-a)

Other simple way if you do not want to redirect stdout and stderr then write your own `fprintf` function which will write all messages in Thread specific files. Here based on Thread_index or thread_number you can choose your File descriptrer and write messages in that.

Comment: But how to make a log file? And how to record stack information?

Comment: log file is just another file. Using fopen() you can create log file.